# Using old versions of vagrant and puphpet

Tags: vagrant, puppet, puphpet

I have puppet 3.4.2 and Vagrant 1.6.5. We configured our puphpet setup over a year ago.

This is all working fine on my environment, but a fresh install downloads a new version of the base box which has an updated version of puppet and so our old configurations don't work.

We are using this box: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/puphpet/boxes/ubuntu1204-x64. I must have v1 but for new instances it will download v2.1

I have tried updating the puphpet config.yaml, but when I upload this to puphpet.com I get the message "The config file provided was empty! Please recreate your manifest manually below.".

So I see a few solutions but I have blockers on each of them:

1. Use the old base box. Is there an archive copy of V1 of this server somewhere on the internet? https://atlas.hashicorp.com/puphpet/boxes/ubuntu1204-x64
2. Use the new base box but downgrade Puppet. How do you downgrade Puppet and all it's dependancies?
3. Figure out some way of importing my config.yaml in to puphpet.com and start using the new versions. Is there anything I need to do to get puphpet.com to recognise an old file?
4. Reconfigure the whole file from scratch. Do you know anyone that can help me?

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 2):

1. It's still there, but no longer supported or publically listed.
2. All boxes come pre-installed with Puppet 3.4.3, which is BC with 3.4.2.
3. Sorry, changes in the past month or two have broken BC with old config.yaml files. You'll need to manually select your options again.
4. Just do this. Honestly, it's textboxes, dropdowns and radio boxes, and will take you less than 10 minutes.

Comment: Thank Juan. I've gone for option 4 and made a lot of progress. However our app was configured with mod_php and we have php_value configs set in the htaccess file and vhosts file. I guess this means puphpet is no longer a good option for us. :(